# Delta distribution doesn't belong to any $L^p$ but there is a $H^1_0$ representation of it, why?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $\Omega := (-1,1)$. I heard that the delta distribution $$\delta\colon H^1_0 \to \mathbb{C},\, \phi \mapsto \phi(0), \,\, \delta \in H^{-1} := (H^1_0(\Omega))'$$ has a Riesz representation in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ and on the other hand doesn't belong to any $L^P$ space. But how is this possible, since $H^1_0(\Omega) \subseteq L^2(\Omega)$?

I'm relatively new to the topic and I feel quite a bit lost. I did some research on this board and found the two threads
[Delta Dirac Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208906/delta-dirac-function/208915#208915) and
[Representing the dirac distribution in $H^1(\mathbb R)$ through the scalar product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538295/representing-the-dirac-distribution-in-h1-mathbb-r-through-the-scalar-produ) , in wich the two assumptions above are proven.

So what I'm getting wrong, why is this no contradiction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point is: different *functions/distributions* may induce the same *linear functional* on a space, acting in different ways. For example, on $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ we have a continuous linear functional $E_0v = v(0)$ (evaluation at $0$). This functional is induced by the function $u(t)=\frac12 e^{-|x|}$ under the action 
$$
v\mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}}(uv+u'v')
$$
On the other hand, the same functional $E_0$ is induced by the distribution $\delta_0$ (Dirac delta) under the action
$$
v\mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}} \delta_0 v
$$
where the   integral isn't really an integral but the action of a distribution.

So: two **different** distributions, acting in **different** ways, yield the same result. The Dirac delta is the distribution that yields $v(0)$ when applied to test function $v$. The function $\frac12 e^{-|x|}$ does not do that: when applied to $v$, it yields $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac12e^{-|x|}v(x)\,dx$, not $v(0)$.

If we use a different way for distributions to induce linear functionals on $H^1$: namely, integrate also against $v'$, then $\frac12e^{-|x|}$ induces $E_0$ functional, and $\delta_0$ induces some unbounded functional.

Functions like $\frac12 e^{-|x|}$ are called a [reproducing kernel for a  Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space).

Here's one more way to look at it: the map $u\mapsto u-u''$ is an isomorphism of $H^1_0(\mathbb{R})$ onto $H^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ which sends $\frac12 e^{-|x|}$ to $\delta_0$. But "isomorphic" does not mean "the same space".

Answer (score 2):

An important issue is this: functions in $H_0^1$ have definite point values, while an element $f$ in $L^p$ is not changed by redefining $f(0)$. So it does not make sense to talk about $\delta$ on $L^p$. A element $f$ of $H_0^1(-1,1)$ is equal a.e. to a *unique* continuous function $\tilde{f}$ on $(-1,1)$, and $\tilde{f}$ is absolutely continuous with $\tilde{f}'\in L^2$. So $\tilde{f}(0)$ has definite meaning, but $\tilde{f}'(0)$ does not.