# Representation of the Delta function, Riesz dual of evaluation at a point $ev_0: W^{1,2}([-1,1]) \to \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, dirac-delta

Consider the [Sobolev Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space)  $W^{1,2}([-1,1])$ (so one weak derivative, $L^2$-integrable)

The linear map $ev_0:W^{1,2}([-1,1])\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f\mapsto f(0)$$
is well defined and *continuous* because Sobolev embedding theorem tells us that $W^{1,2}([-1,1])\to C^0([-1,1])$ is continuous.

It follows by Riesz representation theorem that exists a function $F \in W^{1,2}([-1,1])$ representing $ev_0$, i.e.
$$f(0) = \int_{-1}^1 f(t)F(t)dt + \int_{-1}^1 \partial_t f(t) \partial_tF(t) dt $$
for all $f\in W^{1,2}([-1,1]).$

> What is $F$ explicitely?

My initial idea was to consider $\partial_tF(t)= \mathbb{1}_{[-1,0]}(t)$ characteristic function, so $F(t) = c_0 +  t\mathbb{1}_{[-1,0]}(t) +\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(t)$; however this yields some integral terms that do not look nice:
$$\langle f, F \rangle_{W^{1,2}} = \int_{-1}^0 f(t)t\ dt + \int_{0}^1f(t) \ dt \ +f(0) -f(-1)  $$

Comment: [Guess this is what you mean](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538295/representing-the-dirac-distribution-in-h1-mathbb-r-through-the-scalar-produ)